# I need help finding the interval of convergence for a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need to find the interval of convergence for the following power series:

[image]

I used the ratio test and got (2X)lim(n/n+1) and this is pretty much where I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint, consider the auxiliary series $\sum \dfrac{x^n}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

You didn't *quite* use the ratio test correctly, or there'd be an absolute value. :-)

If our series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{2xn}{n+1}\right\rvert=2\lvert x\rvert\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=2\lvert x\rvert.
$$

The ratio test says that the series will converge if this limit (here, $2\lvert x\rvert$) is strictly smaller than $1$, and diverge if it is strictly larger than $1$.  So, for what values of $x$ does the series converge?  How wide is that set?

Comment: I want to say (-inf, 0)?

Comment: Never mind that doesn't work

Comment: You need $2\lvert x\rvert<1$.

Comment: So wouldn't x need to be zero since the absolute value would change negative to positive?

Comment: What is $\lvert-\frac{1}{4}\rvert$?  Is it less than $\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+1/n}=1$$.  However, when applying the ratio test you need absolute value

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|{(2x)^n\over n}\right|.$$